# PHP - different URL link depending on the web page

Tags: php

Creating a website and in the header I want the URL a link to be different depending on which directory it is.

I want it to be: 
 - If directory1 then link to directory1 URL
 - If directory2 then link to directory2 URL

Can someone help with it?

I found the code below which might be helpful.
Thanks

```
        <?php
        $homepage = "/";
        $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if($homepage==$currentpage) {
        echo '/';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: that would mainly be html unless you want it to have some very special purpose php is not needed for this

Comment: See for URL REWRITING instead of doing it with PHP.

Comment: thank you, the header is already within a separate php file as it is part of a wordpress theme (Avada)

Comment: thanks but I don't think url rewriting would help because it is not changing the URL, just one button on each page

Answer (score 0):

Now i understood your question you wanted to get the main directory. If this is so than explode the url and than replace the http:// or https:// section from the array and than output the variable

```
  <?php
   $url="http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    $url_orignal= explode('/', str_ireplace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $url));
    echo "www.website.com/".$url_orignal[1]; 
    ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks for that, unfortunately it doesn't work for pages outside of the home page,
some of the pages are directories within directories - I don't know if that is causing the problem.

What i think it needs is: 
 - If page is within directoryx, then url = directoryx.

What do you think?

I think it can be done manually like that

Can you help with that code? 
Many thanks for helping with it

Comment: Do you want to get the current url of the directory

Comment: yes I want to get the current director of the first directory, and not including the second directory.
some pages are:
www.website.com/directory1/directory2/page
I want these to go to: 
www.website.com/directory1/

Comment: Do you mean to redirect directory2 to directory1